# How is the size of a filesystem defined?

Tags: filesystems, partition, resize2fs

`man resize2fs` says

> The resize2fs program will resize ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems. It can be used to enlarge or
>   shrink an unmounted file system located on device. ...
>   The `size` parameter specifies the requested new size of the filesystem

How do you choose a `size` parameter to specify to `resize2fs`? More specifically:

How is the size of a filesystem defined?

Does it count external fragmentation and/or internal fragmentation?
If it doesn't count external fragmentation but counts internal fragmentation, the size of a filesystem should be the same, as long as `resize2fs` doesn't modify or remove the existing files.

Does it count [the space for storing inodes and the space for root usage, such as defragmentation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/501280/674)?

[Do `df`'s and `gparted`'s "used" columns show the size of each file system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/501277/) Can the "used" numbers be used for choosing a `size` parameter for `resize2fs`? Note that `df`'s and `gparted`'s "used" columns show different used numbers for the same partition, and not sure why.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of a file system, as used for `resize2fs` (and `mke2fs` and other similar tools) is the external size of the file system, *i.e.* the amount of space it occupies as viewed from the outside. The internal data structures of the file system don’t matter here. Everything in the file system — metadata, data, and unused space within the file system — fits within the file system’s size. This also includes any boot loader hosted in the same partition as the file system, where such a configuration is possible (it is [with Ext2/3/4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Layout), not with XFS, for example).

The best way to determine the current size of a file system is to read it from the file system; for example, for ext2/3/4 file systems, you’d multiply the block count by the block size:

```
dumpe2fs -h /path/to/file/system | grep -E 'Block (count|size):'
```

By default, the size of a file system is usually the size of its container, *e.g.* its containing partition or logical volume. This is the value that `resize2fs` will use if you don’t specify a size explicitly. Specifying `size` is useful when you want to shrink a file system and its container: you’d start by running `resize2fs` with the target size, and then shrink the container (partition, logical volume, etc.) to match.

To determine the minimum size to which you can shrink a file system, the best approach is to use `resize2fs` itself:

```
resize2fs -M -P /path/to/file/system
```

will tell you how many blocks a minimal file system would occupy (preserving all the current contents); to determine the block size used, run

```
dumpe2fs -h /path/to/file/system | grep Block\ size
```

You can get the details of the calculation by adding `-d 32`:

```
resize2fs -d 32 -M -P /path/to/file/system
```

The maximum size of a file system is usually the size of its container (partition or logical volume). A file system which is in a partition or logical volume can never be bigger than the partition or logical volume; there can be additional constraints which limit the extent to which a file system can grow. (File systems stored in image files behave differently, `resize2fs` changes the file size to match the file system size, whether growing or shrinking.)

Comment: Thanks. (1) Since the `size` parameter doesn't mean the target used size in the partition of the file system, an `resize2fs` won't remove or modify existing files in any case, what is the purpose of the `size` parameter? (2) What is "the external size of the file system, i.e. the amount of space it occupies as viewed from the outside"? Does it count external fragmentation and/or internal fragmentation? Does it count the space for storing inodes and the space for root usage (defragmentation)? (3) Can  df's and gparted's "used" columns be useful for   choosing a size parameter for `resize2fs`?

Comment: No, I don't, but I often check if you did. (1) "Everything in the file system — metadata and data — fits within the file system’s size." How about external fragmentation, i.e. the free space holes between files? I believe it counts internal fragmentation. (2) by `resize`, do you mean for terminal?

Comment: (1) Sorry, feel difficulty understanding your analogy. I am surprised that you don't know about it, while it is understandable that I don't. external fragmentation means the free space in the partition is split into pieces by files (or parts of files). So does the size of a file system count the holes between files (or file parts)?

Comment: Forget about partitions, we’re talking about file systems here. The space between files is still inside the file system, so yes, it’s part of the file system’s size. Otherwise a file system’s size would change as you add and remove files.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is the size of a filesystem always the same as the size of its containing volume? Is it correct that `resize2fs` resizes a volume not actually a filesystem? (2) If a file system is resized to be smaller than its containing partition, can I create a second file system directly on the rest of the partition?

Comment: What’s a volume here?

Comment: is a "partition" a volume here?

Comment: I’m asking you. What do you mean by volume?

Comment: a volume is a container of a filesystem. It can be a partition, or something created by LVM

Comment: This all started from the manpage. Did you see the part where it says “The resize2fs program will resize ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems.”?

Comment: "By default, the size of a file system is usually the size of its container, e.g. its containing partition or logical volume." The boot block of a partition is outside a filesystem in it, correct?

Comment: No, the boot block is inside file systems; for example, in ext2 it’s [part of group 0](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Layout).

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I was trying to clarify that the file system’s size isn’t one of the “internal” sizes visible using `df` etc., to address Tim’s questions about fragmentation and so on. In my mind the underlying storage is a separate issue; when you look at the apparent size of a sparse file, you still see the full size (“space it occupies as viewed from the outside”). How can `resize2fs` “help you resize the container in just one run”? I thought that was `fsadm`.

Comment: Sorry about the resize2fs thing, Haven a look at manpage again, I mis-remembered something. Have deleted the original comment and post the first paragraph again. A filesystem can have size 1TiB but actually only occupy 20MiB in the underlying layer of storage. e.g. sparse file used as loop device. It would be more proper to say the size indicated by the filesystem itself.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 I’ve added a paragraph to explain how to determine the current size.

Comment: "the boot block is inside file systems". Is it for all filesystems, most file systems, or just ext filesystems?  Does it mean the first partition contains the partition table for the whole disk?

Comment: File systems which support booting with “old-style” PC boot managers (LILO especially) make allowances for the boot block. File systems which came from non-PC systems don’t; for example, XFS can’t host LILO in the same partition because its superblock goes in block 0. The first partition doesn’t contain the partition table (how would you know where the first partition is if you need to find it before you can read the partition table?).

Comment: What does "make allowances for the boot block" mean? Are ext filesystems "file systems which support booting with “old-style” PC boot managers (LILO especially) " or not? "The first partition doesn’t contain the partition table", do you mean the partition table is   stored outside any partition in any filesystem, regardless of whether the boot loader is stored in a partition or not in any partition?

Comment: “Make allowances for the boot block” means that the file system layout leaves room for the boot loader. Ext2/3/4 support booting with LILO etc.; see the link I gave above for the location of the boot blocks in the ext2/3/4 disk layout. The partition table describes the partitions, so yes, it is stored outside any partition in any file system (and again, file systems and partitions are different, a partition can exist without a file system and vice versa).

Comment: @Tim just search the Wikipedia partition table, you'll know everything

Comment: @stephen Thanks. Is including boot block in filesystem more popular (or better) than not? (in a way similar to GPT better than MBR)

Comment: 30 comments on (counting deleted comments), I think it’s time to draw this conversation to a close. Including the boot block in the file system is moot nowadays, since EFI doesn’t use one any more.