# What is the purpose of `.Trash-1000` in my external hard drive and how can I clean it up?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage

I have a Western Digital external hard drive with one partition and a NTFS filesystem. In Lubuntu, under its top directory:

```
$ sudo du -d 0 -h * | sort -h
0   temp
7.5K    $RECYCLE.BIN
25K System Volume Information
690M    dir1
1.5G    dir2
3.2G    dir3
15G     dir4
71G     dir5
98G     dir6
522G    dir7
```

roughly the drive has 0.7+1.5+3.2+15+71+98+522 = 711.4 G in use.

But

```
$ sudo df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1            932G  880G   53G  95% /media/t/My Passport
```

and gparted  shows the hard drive has 931.48GiB in Size, 879.47GiB Used, and 52.01GiB Unused.

So why do the three ways give different results? Why does the first way give very different result from the the other two  in particular?

Thanks.

---

I just found a hidden directory `.Trash-1000` under the top directory.

```
$ du -h -d 0 .Trash-1000 
166G    .Trash-1000

$ ls .Trash-1000/
expunged  files  info
```

What is the purpose of `.Trash-1000`?

How shall I clean it up? Can I simply `rm -r .Trash-1000`?

Comment: So you already see it's different...

Comment: That's NTFS, so that's probably the "Recycle Bin" from Windows... Not sure whether it's safe to remove it or that might affect how the FS behaves on Windows... (Maybe Superuser SE might be more useful to answer that.)

Answer (score 6):

`.Trash-1000` is the [FreeDesktop.org Trash specification-defined](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html) wastebin for the user with id 1000 (presumably `t`) on the removable drive (the wastebin for your “home” volume is `~/.local/share/Trash`; other volumes get user-specific top-level trash directories). It contains files which were “deleted” using a Trash specification-compliant file manager (for example, any file manager using GVFS).

You can delete it using `rm -rf` without adverse consequences other than permanently deleting its contents. You can also empty it by asking GVFS to empty the wastebin:

```
gvfs-trash --empty
```

or

```
gio trash --empty
```

Comment: Does `gio trash --empty` delete files located in `~/.local/share/Trash/files`? or should I cd into the folder first which contains .Trash-1000 folder?

Comment: Yes, it deletes files there.

Comment: The trash directories are actually not GVFS-specific, but apply to any program implementing the FreeDesktop.org [Trash specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html). They differentiate between home and non-home partitions (rather than removable and non-removable ones). As for non-home partitions, the implementation may trash to a ”top directory“: _If an `$topdir/.Trash` directory is absent, an `$topdir/.Trash-$uid` directory is to be used as the user's trash directory for this device/partition._